# Getting a FileNotFound Exception in .Net core Web API While Running Migration

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm running into this exception while trying to add database migration to my .net core web api project.
The error is around not being able to find the database file. I already created the database in SqlExpress...but for some strange reason, I keep getting this error when I run the command
**Add-Migration DatabaseCreation**

```
Add-Migration DatabaseCreation
```

> Build started... Build succeeded. System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
> Could not load file or assembly 'LafargeDb, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified. File
> name: 'LafargeDb, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'    at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
> codeBase, RuntimeAssembly assemblyContext, StackCrawlMark& stackMark,
> Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext)
> at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
> assemblyRef, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, AssemblyLoadContext
> assemblyLoadContext)    at
> System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef,
> StackCrawlMark& stackMark, AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext)
> at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsAssembly..ctor(ICurrentDbContext
> currentContext, IDbContextOptions options, IMigrationsIdGenerator
> idGenerator, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions) at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope
> serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite
> singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope
> serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite
> singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1
> accessor)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.DesignTimeServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<AddDbContextDesignTimeServices>b__7(IServiceProvider _)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite
> transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.EnsureServices(IServiceProvider services)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action
> action)

I also deleted the database and recreated a new one with a different name, that didn't work either.

Comment: The exception is not for database (add migration command does not need database at all), but the assembly containing your derived `DbContext` class. Run `Add-Migration DatabaseCreation -Verbose` and see the output.

Comment: I ran the verbose command here is what i got back.

Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Using context 'RepositoryContext'.
Finding design-time services for provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer'...
Using design-time services from provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer'.
Finding design-time services referenced by assembly 'LAWebAPI'.
No referenced design-time services were found.
Finding IDesignTimeServices implementations in assembly 'LAWebAPI'...
No design-time services were found.

Comment: Which assembly(project) contains the `RepositoryContext`? `LafargeDb`?

Comment: @IvanStoev The RepositoryContext is in the Entities assembly which is referenced in the main Web API project. i.e LAWebAPI.

Comment: Ok, the exception is about assembly called "LafargeDb", which seems to be the assembly where the migrations should be stored (`MigrationsAssembly` constructor in the exception stack trace). What is "LafargeDb", why EFC is trying to use it as migrations assembly and why it is failing - that's something that cannot be answered w/o seeing your db context configuration and project structure.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it by changing the name to LAWebAPI.